# Modifying spatial widget formsets on Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inline-formset

I am using a `TabularInline` to reorganize some models in the `Django` 1.6 admin. I'm running into difficulty when I try to overwrite the default form that is being used. I've read the relevant portion of the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines). Using `formfield_overrides` I've tried to change a form using this:

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.PointField: {'widget': Textarea},
}
```

I am subclassing the `admin.ModelAdmin` using the following approach:

```
class DirectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):

        overrides = {
            models.PointField: {'widget': Textarea},
        }

        for inline in self.inlines:
            inline.formfield_overrides = overrides
            return inline(self.model, self.admin_site)
```

However, when I try this  approach, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

When I drop into this loop I can see that `inline.formfield_overrides` does exist as an empty dict, but I don't know what the correct values should be. Is this the correct approach? Is there any other way to modify these widgets when models are grouped using `TabularInline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should use formfield_overrides property in TabularInline or StackableInline defenition.

For example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import City, Shop

class ShopInline(admin.TabularInline):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.PointField: {'widget': Textarea},
    }
    model = Shop

class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ShopInline,]
```

But If you want set widget for **all** inlines:

```
class DirectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):

    overrides = {
        models.PointField: {'widget': Textarea},
    }
    inline_instances = super(DirectAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj=obj)
    for inline in inline_instances:
        inline.formfield_overrides = overrides
    return inline_instances
```

For better understanding please inspect [get_inline_instance definition](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L530)